# Correlate a 1d array with every 4d array in python in short time

Tags: python, arrays, scipy, statistics, correlation

I have a a 4d array (called a) with shape(35, 2000, 60, 180) that I need to correlate with a 1d array (called b) that has length of 2000, while detrending and smoothing both arrays.

I managed to use a nested for-loop to correlate the 1d array with the 3d array (called c) shape(x, y, z) by iterating through each point y, z, detrending c[x, y, :] and storing the correlation coefficient between b and at that point.

However, using a 3x-nested for-loop to calculate the correlation with a 4d array takes too much time to compute. Is there a more efficient way to produce an array that contains the correlation coefficient between each timeseries in a 4d array and a 1d array?

Here is my code for calculating the correlation with only 3 dimensions involved. It takes around a minute to execute on an array with shape(2000, 60, 180).

Also, the larger array has nan's, in which case, i set the correlation for the entire x,y point t be nan.

````
def correlation_detrended(cs, ts, smooth=360):

    cs_det = cs
    ts_det = ts
    signal.detrend(ts_det[~np.isnan(ts_det)], overwrite_data=True)
    ts_det = pd.DataFrame(ts_det).rolling(smooth, center=True).mean().to_numpy()[:, 0]


    for i in range(len(cs_det[0, :, 0])):
        for j in range(len(cs_det[0, i, :])):
            print(str(i) + ":" + str(j) )
            if np.any(np.isnan(cs_det[:, i, j])):
                r, p = (np.nan, np.nan)
            else:
                signal.detrend(cs_det[:, i, j], overwrite_data=True)
                cs_det[:, i, j] = pd.DataFrame(cs_det[:, i, j]).rolling(smooth, center=True).mean().to_numpy()[:, 0]
                offset = int((smooth/2+120))
                r, p = stats.pearsonr(cs_det[offset:-(offset), i, j], ts_det[offset:-(offset)])
            correlation[i, j] = r
    return correlation```
````